# Two data-type variables reference eachother in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I have the weirdest bug I've seen in a long time. I'm working in C# in Visual Studio 2017, and I have to data-variables that seem to refer to the same point in the memory.

Specifically, I define the function

```
static void GetDataMoments(IEnumerable<double> vec, out double M2X, out double M2Y, out double M2XY, out double M1Y, out double M1X, out int N)
{
    M2X = 0;
    M2Y = 0;
    M2XY = 0;
    M1Y = 0;
    M1X = 0;
    N = 0;

    foreach (var d in vec)
    {
        M1Y += d;
        M2X += (++N) * N;
        M2XY += d * N;
        M2Y += d * d;
        M1X += N; 
    }

    // For checking
    M1X = (N + 1d) * N / 2; 
}
```

I've had errors with this function, so I debugged it with the

```
double[] vec = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();
```

With that, `M1X` should be equal to `M1Y` at any point, and `M2X == M2Y == M2XY` similarly.

However, debugging the function, at the first line inside the `foreach` section, I get that `M1Y` is increased by d (which is equal `1` at that point), but also `M2Y`!

Did anyone encounter this before? I ran this both in .Net Framework 4.6.2 and 4.7.2, so it's not framework-related.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using `out` parameters, if you pass in the same variable multiple times when calling that method, then yes, they will be the same. ie. `GetDataMoments(..., out a, out a, out a, out a, ...)` <-- this will produce this kind of behavior. Here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CdFr0O - notice I use `out a` twice when calling the method, then observe the behavior of changing `a` and writing out `b`, inside the method.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You are correct - I should've thought of that. I passed a dummy-variable multiple times in a parent-of-a-parent-method. Publish it as an answer.

Comment: Note that if you want throwaway variables, you can from C# 7 and up use *discards*, which is basically the variable `_` (underscore). Every such variable will be distinct, and you don't even need to give it a type or declare it. In other words, `GetDataMoments(..., out _, out _, out _, out _, ...)` would not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is nothing as sinister or unfortunate as a bug in .NET, but just that you've tricked yourself.

Note that I'm going by an assumption, but since I can demonstrate the exact problem you've encountered using this assumption, and it's the only reason I can think of (besides an actual bug), I think it's fairly safe to say that this is your problem.

The problem is not with the code in the question but the code that calls it.

Let me show you:

```
public static void Test(out int a, out int b)
{
    a = b = 0;

    a++;
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

You'd expect this code to output 0, since it increased `a`, but not `b`.

However, if you call it like this:

```
int x;
Test(out x, out x);
```

You're effectively making `a` and `b` both use the same variable, which makes them aliases.

It'll print out `1`.

So essentially you passed the same variable multiple times to your method.